# How do I set position of buttons in an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: excel

I expect this is a simple question but I can't find a workable solution. I have four buttons on a simple spreadsheet that I want to align horizontally with the edge of a column and get a consistent space between them. I have used the "Format Control" option in the Developer Design Mode to get them all to a consistent length and width. My problem now is the placement on the sheet. They are in a position where there is no chance of the addition of rows or columns affecting them. I'd appreciate any help. Thankss.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you.

```
Sub setPosition()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("CommandButton1", "CommandButton2", "CommandButton3", "CommandButton4")).Select

    With Selection
        .Width = 150
        .Height = 30
        .Left = Range("C2").Left 'here you can take the cell of the column
                                 'you want to set as a hedge
    End With

    'Set the top of the buttons with the property "top" of a cell
    Me.CommandButton1.Top = Range("C2").Top
    Me.CommandButton2.Top = Range("C5").Top
    Me.CommandButton3.Top = Range("C8").Top
    Me.CommandButton4.Top = Range("C11").Top

    'optional
    'With this code you can aling and distribute all the shapes (buttons)
    Selection.ShapeRange.Distribute msoDistributeVertically, msoFalse
    Selection.ShapeRange.Distribute msoDistributeHorizontally, msoFalse
    Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, msoFalse
    Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignLefts, msoFalse
End Sub
```

Tell me if you need more information.